ZStack alignment is not showing HStack
I am trying to build a profile using a background image and then adding image profile but I cannot make the profile pic to shows up.
It looks like this:

As you can see the background and the gradient effect I put works, but the image is not showing. The image dflt_profile_image is expected to be on top of the HStack which contain the bkg image.
I tried ZStack instead of the HStack, but it's not working as well.
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                HStack {
                    Image(user.backgroundImage ?? "dflt_profile_bkg")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                }
                .mask(LinearGradient(colors: [.white, .clear, .clear, .clear], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                HStack {
                    Image("dflt_profile_img")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
                }
            }

Is there a way to assign a default value to a variable if the data variable used is empty or nil?
In my case, user.backgroundImage could be nil or an empty string. I would like to see if there is an inline function to do the if nil or empty
I tried this user.backgroundImage?? "dflt_profile_bkg", but it seems only covering nil, but not empty string.

Please show a [mre] - something I can copy and paste into a new project and reproduce the problem.

This problem might be happening because the background image is larger (taller) than the display.

Since the image is scaled-to-fill, it will overflow the top and bottom of the display if its aspect ratio is taller than that of the screen.

The image is currently a regular layer in the ZStack, so this will cause the ZStack to overflow top and bottom too.

Since the ZStack has alignment: .top, this may mean that the profile picture is lost off the top of the display.


Another possible reason is that the profile image is not found - check for errors in the console.
In any case, I would suggest showing the background image using a .background modifier, instead of as a layer in the ZStack. This way, it doesn't impact the size of the ZStack.
Other suggestions:

In order to make sure that the ZStack still occupies the full screen, set a .frame with maximum width and height. It doesn't have to be a ZStack by the way, you could change it to a VStack if it would be more suitable.

The background image doesn't need .scaledToFit() if you are also applying .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill). The modifier .scaledToFill() is perhaps a simpler way to scale-to-fill.

The images do not need to be nested inside HStacks, the .mask can be applied to the background image directly.

The way you are creating the LinearGradient with 1 x white and 3 x clear colors is fine. But you can create the gradient more precisely by using color stops instead.

Add .ignoresSafeArea() after the mask if you want the image and mask to extend to the borders of the display.


Regarding your question about a default value for a String property that may be nil or empty, I would suggest using a computed property with a conditional binding:
private var backgroundImageName: String {
    if let name = user.backgroundImage, name != "" {
        name
    } else {
        "dflt_profile_bkg"
    }
}

So here is the fully updated example:
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
    Image("dflt_profile_img")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
.background {
    Image(backgroundImageName)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .mask(
            LinearGradient(
                stops: [
                    .init(color: .white, location: 0),
                    .init(color: .clear, location: 0.25)
                ],
                startPoint: .top,
                endPoint: .bottom
            )
        )
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}


